# Inserting text effect into a table cell

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wish to insert a certain text effect object into a given cell of a table.
The macro below demonstrates the problem.

Note: It start with clearing the active document (handy for debugging).
It then creates a table with some rows and columns and sets the height of the rows.
I then try to insert a text effect object in cell (2,4), but it is put in cell (2,1).
The target cell is selected just to be sure.

Note that Word finds the correct row, number 2, but fails to use the wanted column.
My question: How to amend the macro below so that it places the text object in the designated cell?

```
Sub DemoTextEffectProblem()
    Const NoOfRows = 3
    Const NoOfCols = 4
    Const RowHeight = 25
    Dim RowNo As Long
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim cll As Word.Cell
    Dim shp As Word.Shape
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    doc.Content.Delete
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=doc.Range, _
        NumRows:=NoOfRows, NumColumns:=NoOfCols, _
        DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior)
    For RowNo = 1 To NoOfRows
        tbl.Rows(RowNo).Height = MillimetersToPoints(RowHeight)
    Next RowNo
    Set cll = tbl.Cell(2, 4)
    Set shp = doc.Shapes.AddTextEffect( _
                PresetTextEffect:=msoTextEffect13, _
                Text:="Wow!", FontName:="Arial Black", _
                FontSize:=32, fontBold:=msoFalse, fontItalic:=msoFalse, _
                Left:=0, Top:=0, _
                Anchor:=cll.Range)
    cll.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If my answer resolved your question, please accept it by clicking on the grey tick (check) next to it, this helps other users to identify answered questions.

Comment: I should have known. Done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the relevant line with this:

```
    Set shp = doc.Shapes.AddTextEffect( _
                PresetTextEffect:=msoTextEffect13, _
                Text:="Wow!", FontName:="Arial Black", _
                FontSize:=32, FontBold:=msoFalse, FontItalic:=msoFalse, _
                Left:=0, Top:=0, _
                Anchor:=doc.Range(cll.Range.Start, cll.Range.Start))
```

Comment: You need to explain why this revised code is appropriate.  Just presenting code on its own is not a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Specifying the Anchor as you suggested really did the trick, thank you very much!